# HTML | Select Tag | AngularJS | Blank option are displayed in Safari and Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, safari

Im using the next html + Angulrjs code is order to create a dropdown list.

```
 <li class="category-li" ng-if="!eventDetailsCtrl.showRule && !(eventDetailsCtrl.pageType == 'incident' || eventDetailsCtrl.pageType == 'anomaly')"><span class="fontBold">Close Reason: &nbsp;</span>
                    <select class="event-details-category-select" ng-model="eventDetailsCtrl.eventData.closingReason" name="" id="category" ng-options="category for category in eventDetailsCtrl.categories" ng-change="eventDetailsCtrl.categoryUpdate(eventDetailsCtrl.eventData.closingReason)">
                        <option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
                    </select>
</li>
```

At first, the dropdown list displayed blank option (an empty option) in addition to the options from category so I added this line

```
<option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
```

it worked fine with Chrome, Firefox and Edge BUT I still see the blank line in Explorer11 and safari

can someone give me advice?

Comment: Do you mean when you run your code with the IE 11 browser it looks like this [test result](https://imgur.com/a/xPasI4g)? If yes, you can add an option like `<option value="">--Select--</option>` can help to work around this issue. [See here](https://imgur.com/Dv6a0G0). If the issue is different then I suggest you please share the snapshot of the issue may help to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Yes, the issue is like you presented in the [test result](https://imgur.com/a/xPasI4g) link. At first I had this issue with all the browsers and then I added this line `<option value="" ng-show="false"></option>` which worked for the browsers Chrome, Edge and firefox but not for safari and explorer.

Comment: Does the workaround for you? If yes, let me know. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: should I used it instead of the code that I tried to worked with or in addition?

Comment: You can replace the `<option value="" ng-show="false"></option>` with `<option value="">--Select--</option>`.

Comment: Yes it worked but then --Select-- is an option and the user can "choose" it if you know what I mean.

Comment: In that case, we can use `<option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you replace the `<option value="" ng-show="false"></option>` with `<option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>`.

It can help you to fix the issue with the IE 11 browser.

```
<span class="fontBold">Close Reason: &nbsp;</span>
<select >
<option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
<option value="1">Reason-1</option>
<option value="2">Reason-2</option>
<option value="3">Reason-3</option>
</select>
```

Output:

[image]